# Create a rotating camera in ThreeJS

Tags: three.js

Is there an easy way to create a camera control that has the camera rotating on a point? It seems like there would be a set of controls for this "out of the box", but I cannot manipulate any of the controls the way I want to. What I am trying to do is put a camera in each corner of the room I am working on. Sort of like surveillance cameras that I can use the mouse controls to look around from a fixed position. Please Help.

Comment: I tried implementing the FirstPersonControls, which work in a way, but the camera does some spinning on its own that I cannot figure out, and the first click and drag will swing the camera around 18 degrees.

Comment: here is an example of what is happening.
http://protest.jhtinc.com/duke/er/scene1.html

Comment: That link doesn't work. This one does.
http://jht-elearning.com/duke/er/scene1.html